# Ubuntu 16.04LTS reboots often without any error message

Tags: 16.04, crash, reboot

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my old machine where windows was running before. System boots up successfully, I can see the desktop. Most of the time when I try to open mozilla or or just a terminal whole machine get non-responding and then after some seconds I see system is rebooting. This behavior is not consistent, sometimes everything works fine. I have more than 10 times crash since yesterday. I am new to Ubuntu. I found from google how to look into logs but I could not figure out what is problem. I am posting my logs '/var/logs/syslogs'. It looks like crash happens at around 11:16:41.

```
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [   81.658720] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [   81.658723] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [   81.658726] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [   81.658729] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [   81.658733] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [   81.658736] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [   81.658739] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [   81.658741] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [   81.663814] wls3: authenticated
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 wpa_supplicant[1197]: wls3: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 NetworkManager[1009]: <info>  [1523783795.4162] device (wls3): supplicant interface state: completed -> authenticating
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 wpa_supplicant[1197]: wls3: Trying to associate with 78:94:b4:58:83:d8 (SSID='EasyBox-284884' freq=2437 MHz)
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [   81.668082] wls3: associate with 78:94:b4:58:83:d8 (try 1/3)
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [   81.676121] wls3: RX AssocResp from 78:94:b4:58:83:d8 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 NetworkManager[1009]: <info>  [1523783795.4372] device (wls3): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 wpa_supplicant[1197]: wls3: Associated with 78:94:b4:58:83:d8
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [   81.703031] wls3: associated
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 wpa_supplicant[1197]: wls3: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 78:94:b4:58:83:d8 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 wpa_supplicant[1197]: wls3: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 78:94:b4:58:83:d8 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 NetworkManager[1009]: <info>  [1523783795.4877] device (wls3): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Apr 15 11:16:35 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 NetworkManager[1009]: <info>  [1523783795.4885] device (wls3): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Apr 15 11:16:40 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 fwupd[2129]: (fwupd:2129): Fu-WARNING **: disabling plugin because: failed to coldplug raspberrypi: Raspberry PI firmware updating not supported, no /boot/start.elf
Apr 15 11:16:40 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 fwupd[2129]: (fwupd:2129): Fu-WARNING **: disabling plugin because: failed to coldplug uefi: UEFI firmware updating not supported
Apr 15 11:16:41 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 dbus[973]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.fwupd'
Apr 15 11:16:41 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 systemd[1]: Started Firmware update daemon.
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="963" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 systemd-modules-load[356]: Inserted module 'lp'
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 systemd-modules-load[356]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 rsyslogd-2222: command 'KLogPermitNonKernelFacility' is currently not permitted - did you already set it via a RainerScript command (v6+ config)? [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2222 ]
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 108
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 104
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 systemd-modules-load[356]: Inserted module 'parport_pc'
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 systemd[1]: Started LVM2 metadata daemon.
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 systemd[1]: Started Apply Kernel Variables.
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 loadkeys[358]: Loading /etc/console-setup/cached.kmap.gz
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 systemd[1]: Started Set console keymap.
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 systemd[1]: Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 lvm[365]:   2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" monitored
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 systemd[1]: Started Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling.
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 systemd[1]: Started Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Random Seed...
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 systemd[1]: Reached target Local File Systems (Pre).
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.4.0-119-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-013) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) ) #143-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 2 16:08:24 UTC 2018 (Ubuntu 4.4.0-119.143-generic 4.4.114)
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for core...
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for skype...
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Apr 15 11:18:59 yasar-ThinkPad-T61 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Legacy x87 FPU detected.
```

Result of 'last' command.

```
yasar    tty7         :0               Sun Apr 15 13:47    gone - no logout
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-119-generi Sun Apr 15 12:48   still running
yasar    tty7         :0               Sun Apr 15 12:46 - crash  (00:02)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-119-generi Sun Apr 15 12:45   still running
yasar    tty7         :0               Sun Apr 15 12:39 - down   (00:01)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-119-generi Sun Apr 15 12:38 - 12:40  (00:02)
yasar    tty7         :0               Sun Apr 15 12:31 - down   (00:05)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-119-generi Sun Apr 15 12:30 - 12:36  (00:06)
yasar    tty7         :0               Sun Apr 15 12:27 - down   (00:01)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-119-generi Sun Apr 15 12:26 - 12:29  (00:02)
yasar    tty7         :0               Sun Apr 15 12:14 - down   (00:11)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-119-generi Sun Apr 15 12:13 - 12:26  (00:12)
yasar    tty7         :0               Sun Apr 15 12:11 - crash  (00:01)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-119-generi Sun Apr 15 12:11 - 12:26  (00:15)
yasar    tty7         :0               Sun Apr 15 11:19 - down   (00:51)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-119-generi Sun Apr 15 11:18 - 12:10  (00:51)
yasar    tty7         :0               Sun Apr 15 11:16 - crash  (00:02)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-119-generi Sun Apr 15 11:15 - 12:10  (00:54)
yasar    tty7         :0               Sun Apr 15 11:05 - crash  (00:09)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-119-generi Sun Apr 15 11:04 - 12:10  (01:05)
yasar    tty7         :0               Sat Apr 14 17:16 - down   (17:47)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-119-generi Sat Apr 14 16:14 - 11:04  (18:50)
yasar    tty7         :0               Sat Apr 14 13:20 - crash  (02:54)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-119-generi Sat Apr 14 13:19 - 11:04  (21:44)
yasar    tty4                          Sat Apr 14 13:15 - down   (00:01)
yasar    tty4                          Sat Apr 14 13:14 - 13:14  (00:00)
yasar    tty3                          Sat Apr 14 13:11 - down   (00:04)
yasar    tty7         :0               Sat Apr 14 13:07 - down   (00:09)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-119-generi Sat Apr 14 13:06 - 13:16  (00:10)
yasar    tty7         :0               Sat Apr 14 13:04 - crash  (00:01)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-119-generi Sat Apr 14 13:03 - 13:16  (00:13)
yasar    tty7         :0               Fri Apr 13 00:04 - crash (1+12:59)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-119-generi Fri Apr 13 00:03 - 13:16 (1+13:13)
yasar    tty7         :0               Thu Apr 12 23:59 - crash  (00:04)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-119-generi Thu Apr 12 23:58 - 13:16 (1+13:18)
yasar    tty7         :0               Thu Apr 12 23:52 - crash  (00:05)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-119-generi Thu Apr 12 23:51 - 13:16 (1+13:25)
yasar    tty7         :0               Thu Apr 12 23:50 - crash  (00:01)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-119-generi Thu Apr 12 23:49 - 13:16 (1+13:27)
yasar    tty7         :0               Thu Apr 12 23:43 - crash  (00:05)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-119-generi Thu Apr 12 23:42 - 13:16 (1+13:33)
yasar    tty7         :0               Thu Apr 12 22:57 - crash  (00:45)
reboot   system boot  4.4.0-38-generic Thu Apr 12 22:56 - 13:16 (1+14:19)
guest-ab tty8         :1               Thu Apr 12 23:02 - crash  (00:-6)
```

Comment: Ubuntu does not have a "sudden reboot without warning" feature (who would want that?)...but your hardware does. The most common reasons for an unlogged reboot are 1) Overheating and 2) Bad Power Supply. Start searching on how to rule out those first.

Comment: Yes, when my ubuntu was crashing without any message, i also thought who would want that. but as I mentioned earlier I want to diagnose the reason. I have posted the result of last command. By the way, why ubuntu cannot tell me before shtting down if it was because of high temperature? for me doesnt make sense.

Comment: It cannot be because of power supply, because It always hangs before crashing. So it is something else. I am new and I want to know how to diagnose it.

Comment: @starkus 'purging fwupd' doent crash the system. I tried it.